# Why is my controller property 'undefined' when I assign it the result of $resource query()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I have a JSON data structure:

```
 [
{
"title"  :"a1",
"id"     :"b1",
"name"   :"c1"
},
{
"title"  :"a2",
"id"     :"b2",
"name"   :"c2"
}
 ]
```

I am accessing is as an external JSON and parsed through a factory method. I want it to assign it to a Javascript variable in my controller.

```
 function Control($scope,data)

 {

 var e=data.query();   /* getting the external JSON data  */
 alert(e[0].title);    

}
```

It says that `e[0]` is undefined. Is there any other way I can assign it to a Javascript variable and then traverse through it? Please help.

Comment: Not sure what `.query()` does but assuming it's an asynchronous call meaning your data isn't loaded yet when you do your `alert()`.

Comment: Query actually fetches the result. I am able to access the data from the template but not from the controller

Comment: I'm assuming that the 'template' (sorry I have no experience with Angular)` beings working after all your external data has loaded.

Comment: I want it more generalised. I want it to get access in the javscript controller.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what your `data.query()` actually does? What does it return exactly (an Object, promise, etc...)?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, @Marty is correct.  If you are using the query() method from the $resource service, it is asynchronous.  This will likely do what you want:

```
data.query( function( data ) {
  var e = data;
  alert(e[0].title);
});
```

Comment: Well, at least today my answer was different from yours. ;)

Comment: Looks good but what's the advantage in having e = data there?

Comment: @Marty, I was just following the code given.  I would most likely set some $scope property to store the data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so $resource can be confusing like this... It immediately gives you a reference to the return object, but doesn't update the object until the asynchronous AJAX call returns... so...

If you put your return value from data.query() in a property on $scope, since it's $watched when you bind it in your view, you'll see it update. HOWEVER, if you're just trying to alert it, it will alert the value before it's been updated.. again because of the async aspect of $resource.

Otherwise, you can get the value the way that @MarkRajcok has shown in his answer.

Here is a psuedo-code illustration of ways you can use $resource query();

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
     var Bar = $resource('/Bar/:id', {id: '@id'});

     // here, we get the result reference and stick it in the scope,
     // relying on a digest to update the value on our screen.
     $scope.data = Bar.query();

     //OR

     //here we already have a reference.
     var test = Bar.query(function() {
          //in here, test has been populated.
          $scope.data2 = test;
     });
     alert(test); //not populated here, yet.

     //OR

     Bar.query(function(x) {
          $scope.data3 = x;
     });
});
```

This is all done so the object(s) returned can have functions pre-instantiated on them like $save(), etc.