# How to access an array in AngularJS controller populated by $resource get()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-scope

I can not access an array in the AngularJS controller but it works in the view.

In the controller: `.results` returns undefined

```
function TwitterCtrl($scope, $resource){

  $scope.twitter = $resource('http://search.twitter.com/:action',
      {action:'search.json', q:'angularjs', callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
      {get:{method:'JSONP', params: {rpp: 4}}});

    $scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get({q:"example"});

    //returns the resource object
    console.log($scope.twitterResult)

    //returns undefined
    console.log($scope.twitterResult.results);
}
```

In the view: `.results` returns an array of tweets

```
//This returns an array of tweets
{{$scope.twitterResult.results}}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373661/angularjs-data-assignment

Comment: Thanks mark. That post describes what I've been trying to achieve. I put all of my code in the `success` callback in order to use the `results` array. I wish I could assign the array to a variable and access it outside of that function.

Comment: You can do that -- e.g., $scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get(...)` -- as long as you also add a `$watch('twitterResult', function(newValue) { ... })` to detect when it gets asynchronously updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$resource calls are asynchronous, but $resource service returns a blank object for `resource.get` calls immediately on invocation (or empty array on `resource.query` calls). Then, only after the promise gets resolved (server returns response), the $resource service assigns the actual results to the `$scope.twitterResult` variable.

That's why `$scope.twitterResult` is blank on immediate access (console.log), but (seemingly) 'works' in your view.

Your view expression `{{$scope.twitterResult.results}}` is also undefined at first, but Angular's $parse service (responsible for parsing view expressions) does not output `undefined` because it's designed not to. As soon as server response is received, the view expression is updated, and `twitterResult.results` are displayed.

Comment: `$scope.twitterResult` is not blank when using `console.log` in the controller. It returns the resource object. I can see the `results` array that I want to access when it's logged. However, I get `undefined` when I use `$scope.twitterResult.results` in the controller.

Comment: @Dru, by the time you manually click the `twitterResult` array in the console, the `results` have been populated (asynchronously).  This is the way Chrome works.  If you instead log `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.twitterResult))` you will see that `results` are not populated at the time this statement actually executes.