# How does AngularJS return a value from async call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Watch this video,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRelx4-ISbs

You'll find that the code has a line wrote this:

```
$scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get({q:$scope.searchTerm});
```

This is a litter quirk:
the 'get' method of 'twitter' is obviously a async function, how does it return a value to $scope.twitterResult???

jsFiddle(Can't work cause the twitter API has changed):

http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/qmNvq/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15464273/497356

Answer (score 0):

This code  `$scope.twitter.get({q:$scope.searchTerm});` return defer object. Angular view arranged so that view will be update when defer object resolve. It's just a convenience.

Comment: But how does the deferred object knows which variable should it change? Or the deferred object can change itself?

Comment: When Angular encounters a promise inside the view, it automatically sets up a success callback and substitutes the promise for the resulting value once it has been resolved.
Using promises directly on the view is a feature of AngularJS that many people are unaware of, but it opens up a lot of opportunities for making our controllers as lean as possible.
Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/pL4lF9JYXZ7EVJNv7PJK?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.twitterResult = $scope.twitter.get({q:$scope.searchTerm});
```

Your code is good for only angular binding.

But if you need to get data on run time, you need to write this below format.

If `$scope.twitter` is a URL,Then write it

```
$http.get($scope.twitter, {q:$scope.searchTerm}).success(function (response) {
$scope.twitterResult=response;
}
```

**$http is must defined in contoller**